# php array interchange key value between two array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 array like

```
array (
  0 => 'END PIECE',
  1 => 'END PIECE',
  2 => 'END PIECE',
  3 => 'Title translation test 2',
  4 => 'Title translation test 2',
  5 => 'PIÈCE D\'EXTRÉMITÉ'
);
```

and

```
array (
  0 => '47933',
  1 => '47935',
  2 => '47936',
  3 => '47929',
  4 => '47930',
  5 => '47933'
);
```

I want to make ONE array from this 2 array like

```
array (
  'END PIECE' => '47933',
  'END PIECE' => '47935',
  'END PIECE' => '47936',
  'Title translation test' => '47929',
  'Title translation test' => '47930',
  'PIÈCE D\'EXTRÉMITÉ' => '47933'
);
```

Is it possible? PHP 5.3 version required, I have tried this

```
$c = array();
foreach($arr1 as $k => $val){
    $c[] = array($arr2[$k] => $val);
}
```

But it not works

Comment: `$c[$arr2[$k]] = $val;`

Comment: @NigelRen my main issue is duplicate key not working, which expected as above desired result I have shared

Comment: Your output is basically invalid, you would have to have something like `'END PIECE' => [1,2,3]`

Comment: @NigelRen right, however `END PIECE' => [1,2,3]` also ok, if you can suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, the simple version will always have a subarray...

```
$c = array();
foreach($arr1 as $k => $val){
    $c[$arr2[$k]][] = $val;
}

print_r($c);
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [END PIECE] => Array
        (
            [0] => 47933
            [1] => 47935
            [2] => 47936
        )

    [Title translation test 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 47929
            [1] => 47930
        )

    [PIÈCE D'EXTRÉMITÉ] => Array
        (
            [0] => 47933
        )

)
```

If you only want duplicates to have sub arrays, then you need to check when adding a new item if the item is already set and already an array, adjusting as you go along...

```
$c = array();
foreach($arr1 as $k => $val){
    if ( isset ($c[$arr2[$k]])) {
        if ( !is_array($c[$arr2[$k]]) )
            $c[$arr2[$k]] = [$c[$arr2[$k]]];
        $c[$arr2[$k]][] = $val;
    }
    else    {
        $c[$arr2[$k]] = $val;
    }
}
print_r($c);
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [END PIECE] => Array
        (
            [0] => 47933
            [1] => 47935
            [2] => 47936
        )

    [Title translation test 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 47929
            [1] => 47930
        )

    [PIÈCE D'EXTRÉMITÉ] => 47933
)
```

As you can see, the PIÈCE D'EXTRÉMITÉ element is different in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_combine() function it is working  (PHP 5, PHP 7) like the following

```
$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [green]  => avocado
    [red]    => apple
    [yellow] => banana
)
```

Comment: It is not working as same key required for multiple value